# Python pandas into azure SQL, bulk insert

Tags: python-3.x, azure-sql-database

How can I arrange bulk insert of python dataframe into corresponding azure SQL.
I see that INSERT works with individual records :

INSERT INTO XX ([Field1]) VALUES (value1);

How can I  insert the entire content of dataframe into Azure table?

Thanks

Comment: You can write dataframe  to csv file then use sql command `BULK INSERT` to insert data.

Comment: Thanks , BULK INSERT operates with MS AZURE data. How can I pass a table of data to be insert to BULK INSERT command ?

Comment: Regarding BULK INSERT command, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thanks , BULK INSERT operates with data available in MS AZURE or in the file , my data is in the dataframe that exceeds the size of regular csv file

Comment: You can use `pandas.DataFrame.to_sql` to insert data : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html

Comment: I am gonna insert into AZURE , to_sql is not supposed to help me

Answer (score 4):

According to my test, we also can use `to_sql` to insert data to Azure sql

for example

```
from urllib.parse import quote_plus

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, event

import pyodbc
# azure sql connect tion string
conn ='Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:<server name>.database.windows.net,1433;Database=<db name>;Uid=<user name>;Pwd=<password>;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;'
quoted = quote_plus(conn)
engine=create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(quoted))

@event.listens_for(engine, 'before_cursor_execute')
def receive_before_cursor_execute(conn, cursor, statement, params, context, executemany):
    print("FUNC call")
    if executemany:
        cursor.fast_executemany = True

#insert 
table_name = 'Sales'
# For test, I use a csv file to create dataframe  
df = pd.read_csv('D:\data.csv')
df.to_sql(table_name, engine, index=False, if_exists='replace', schema='dbo')

#test after inserting
query = 'SELECT * FROM {table}'.format(table=table_name )
dfsql = pd.read_sql(query, engine)
print(dfsql)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it generates an error     return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Comment: Is there any chance for book a private session with you? ($$)